# How can I make an "are you sure" prompt in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that automates copying a bunch of files from one place to the other and back for me. Only thing is as much as it helps me I keep accidentally selecting that command off my command buffer and mass overwriting uncommitted changes.

What code would I need for my .bat file to make it output "**Are you sure?**", and make me type <kbd>Y</kbd> before it ran the rest of the file?

If anything other than <kbd>Y</kbd> is typed, it should exit execution on that line.

When I call `exit`, it closes `cmd.exe` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You want something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Are you sure (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END

echo ... rest of file ...


:END
endlocal
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is an additional `SET AREYOUSURE=N` before the prompt in order to clear the choice if you already ran the script before in that command window.  Without it the default will remain the previously selected choice.

Comment: @Igal I'm pretty sure that the `setlocal` and the `endlocal` should take care of that. `%AREYOUSURE%` won't exist anymore after the `endlocal`.

Comment: @dudeprgm you're probably right.  I think that I missed those in my code.

Comment: ...would be more valuable with some explanatory words about the **important two lines**.

Comment: @Joe Maybe he _can't_ because (like me) he doesn't (yet) understand them. So if you do, it would be amazing if you could expand on your answer or link to resources explaining it :)

Comment: Some additional information for completeness: The code as is works only if command extensions are enabled which is the case by Windows default, but is not made explicitly sure. The code results in an exit of batch file processing on user enters by mistake `"` instead of `n` or `N` or any other character. The batch code does something completely different on user enters for example the string `" == "" call echo Hello "%USERNAME%"& echo Your desktop contains the files and folders:& call dir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" & rem ` and so the batch file with such a prompt can be hijacked.

Comment: Line: `SET /P AREYOUSURE=Are you sure (Y/[N])?` should be replaced by 
`SET /P AREYOUSURE=Are you sure Y/[N]? `
(no ( ) ), since will affect the code.

Answer (score 43):

try the [CHOICE command](http://www.computerhope.com/choicehl.htm), e.g.

```
CHOICE /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
```

Comment: <show off>Though this is relatively new. It was added in MS-DOS 6 in 1993 or 1994, so it may not work with all implementations</show off>

Comment: example of how to actually use choice here http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001674.htm

Comment: doesn't actually explain what to do after that command. sure it links to a web page, but that page could be removed at any time. Mofi's answer is much better

Answer (score 29):

There are two commands available for user prompts on Windows command line:

- [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) with option `/P` available on all Windows NT versions with enabled command extensions **and**
- [choice.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/choice) available by default on Windows Vista and later Windows versions for PC users and on Windows Server 2003 and later server versions of Windows.

[set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) is an internal command of Windows command processor `cmd.exe`. The option `/P` to prompt a user for a string is available only with enabled command extensions which are enabled by default as otherwise nearly no batch file would work anymore nowadays.

[choice.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) is a separate console application (external command) located in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. File `choice.exe` of Windows Server 2003 can be copied into directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` on a Windows XP machine for usage on Windows XP like many other commands not available by default on Windows XP, but available by default on Windows Server 2003.

It is best practice to favor usage of **CHOICE** over usage of **SET /P** because of the following reasons:

1. **CHOICE** accepts only keys (respectively characters read from **STDIN**) specified after option `/C` (and <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Break</kbd>) and outputs an error beep if the user presses a wrong key.
2. **CHOICE** does not require pressing any other key than one of the acceptable ones. **CHOICE** exits immediately once an acceptable key is pressed while **SET /P** requires that the user finishes input with <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
3. It is possible with **CHOICE** to define a default option and a timeout to automatically continue with default option after some seconds without waiting for the user.
4. The output is better on answering the prompt automatically from another batch file which calls the batch file with the prompt using something like `echo Y | call PromptExample.bat` on using **CHOICE**.
5. The evaluation of the user's choice is much easier with **CHOICE** because of **CHOICE** exits with a value according to pressed key (character) which is assigned to **ERRORLEVEL** which can be easily evaluated next.
6. The environment variable used on **SET /P** is not defined if the user hits just key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and it was not defined before prompting the user. The used environment variable on **SET /P** command line keeps its current value if defined before and user presses just <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
7. The user has the freedom to enter anything on being prompted with **SET /P** including a string which results later in an exit of batch file execution by `cmd` because of a syntax error, or in execution of commands not included at all in the batch file on not good coded batch file. It needs some efforts to get **SET /P** secure against by mistake or intentionally wrong user input.

Here is a prompt example using preferred **CHOICE** and alternatively **SET /P** on `choice.exe` not available on used computer running Windows.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo This is an example for prompting a user.
echo(
if exist "%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe" goto UseChoice

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:UseSetPrompt
set "UserChoice="
set /P "UserChoice=Are you sure [Y/N]? "
set "UserChoice=!UserChoice: =!"
if /I "!UserChoice!" == "N" endlocal & exit /B
if /I not "!UserChoice!" == "Y" goto UseSetPrompt
endlocal
goto Continue

:UseChoice
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C YN /N /M "Are you sure [Y/N]?"
if not errorlevel 1 goto UseChoice
if errorlevel 2 exit /B

:Continue
echo So you are sure. Okay, let's go ...
rem More commands can be added here.
endlocal
```

**Note:** This batch file uses command extensions which are not available on Windows 95/98/ME using `command.com` instead of `cmd.exe` as command interpreter.

The command line `set "UserChoice=!UserChoice: =!"` is added to make it possible to call this batch file with `echo Y | call PromptExample.bat` on Windows NT4/2000/XP and do not require the usage of `echo Y| call PromptExample.bat`. It deletes all spaces from string read from **STDIN** before running the two string comparisons.

`echo Y | call PromptExample.bat` results in **Y**<kbd>SPACE</kbd> getting assigned to environment variable `UserChoice`. That would result on processing the prompt twice because of `"Y "` is neither case-insensitive equal `"N"` nor `"Y"` without deleting first all spaces. So `UserChoice` with **Y**<kbd>SPACE</kbd> as value would result in running the prompt a second time with option `N` as defined as default in the batch file on second prompt execution which next results in an unexpected exit of batch file processing. Yes, secure usage of **SET /P** is really tricky, isn't it?

`choice.exe` exits with `0` in case of the user presses <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Break</kbd> and answers next the question output by `cmd.exe` to terminate the batch job with <kbd>N</kbd> for NO. For that reason the condition `if not errorlevel 1 goto UserChoice` is added to prompt the user once again for a definite answer on the prompt by batch file code with <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd>. Thanks to [dialer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653473/dialer) for the information about this possible special use case.

The first line below the batch label `:UseSetPrompt` could be written also as:

```
set "UserChoice=N"
```

In this case the user choice input is predefined with `N` which means the user can hit just <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Break</kbd> and next <kbd>N</kbd>) to use the default choice.

The prompt text is output by command **SET** as written in the batch file. So the prompt text should end usually with a space character. The command **CHOICE** removes from prompt text all trailing normal spaces and horizontal tabs and then adds itself a space to the prompt text. Therefore the prompt text of command **CHOICE** can be written without or with a space at end. That does not make a difference on displayed prompt text on execution.

The order of user prompt evaluation could be also changed completely as suggested by [dialer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653473/dialer).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo This is an example for prompting a user.
echo(
if exist "%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe" goto UseChoice

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:UseSetPrompt
set "UserChoice="
set /P "UserChoice=Are you sure [Y/N]? "
set "UserChoice=!UserChoice: =!"
if /I not "!UserChoice!" == "Y" endlocal & exit /B
endlocal
goto Continue

:UseChoice
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C YN /N /M "Are you sure [Y/N]?"
if not errorlevel 2 if errorlevel 1 goto Continue
exit /B

:Continue
echo So you are sure. Okay, let's go ...
endlocal
```

This code results in continuation of batch file processing below the batch label `:Continue` if the user pressed definitely key <kbd>Y</kbd>. In all other cases the code for <kbd>N</kbd> is executed resulting in an exit of batch file processing with this code independent on user pressed really that key, or entered something different intentionally or by mistake, or pressed <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Break</kbd> and decided next on prompt output by `cmd` not terminating the batch job.

For even more details on usage of **SET /P** and **CHOICE** for prompting user for a choice from a list of options see answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Some more hints:

1. **IF** compares the two strings left and right of the comparison operator with **including** the double quotes. So case-insensitive compared is not the value of `UserChoice` with `N` and `Y`, but the value of `UserChoice` surrounded by `"` with `"N"` and `"Y"`.
2. The **IF** comparison operators `EQU` and `NEQ` are designed primary for comparing two integers in range -2147483648 to 2147483647 and not for comparing two strings. `EQU` and `NEQ` work also for string comparisons, but result on comparing strings in double quotes after a useless attempt to convert left string to an integer. `EQU` and `NEQ` can be used only with enabled command extensions. The comparison operators for string comparisons are `==` and `not ... ==` which work even with disabled command extensions as even `command.com` of MS-DOS and Windows 95/98/ME supported them. For more details on **IF** comparison operators see [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564).
3. The command `goto :EOF` requires enabled command extensions to really exit the batch file processing. For more details see [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564) There can be used also `exit /B` which works even with disabled command extensions, but outputs an error message on disabled command extension. `exit /B 2>nul` can be used in any execution environment to exit the processing of a batch file without showing even an error message. In the two batch file examples is used `exit /B` because of being shorter than `goto :EOF`. Both commands work in the examples as the execution environment is completely defined at top of the batch file with the first two command lines.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
  It explains the reason for using syntax `set "variable=value"` on assigning a string to an environment variable.
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for details on `if errorlevel X` behavior and  operator `&`.
- Microsoft documentation for [using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) explaining the redirection operator `|` and handle **STDIN**.
- Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for an explanation of `SystemRoot`.
- DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Comment: choice.exe was also around in DOS since 6.0

Comment: @BrianMinton That is not right. There was available the 16-bit application `CHOICE.COM` by default on MS-DOS 6.0, MS-DOS 7.0, Windows 95 and Windows 98. But there was no `choice.exe` installed by default on Windows NT4, Windows 2000 and Windows XP. `CHOICE.COM` could be used also on NT4, Windows 2000 and Windows XP, but it would be better to use 32-bit `choice.exe` from appropriate resource kit. See Rob van der Woude´s page about [CHOICE](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php). The options are partly different between `CHOICE.COM` and `choice.exe`. However, the question is not about DOS.

Comment: You have a Yes/Cancel situation here ("Cancel" being disguised as "No"), Don't do `if Cancel do CancelAction else do YesAction`. Instead, do `if Yes do YesAction else do CancelAction` or `if not Yes do CancelAction else do YesAction`. The point is, do not check use *Cancel* condition in the if. Use the *Yes* condition. This also applies to *CHOICE*. *CHOICE* can return 0 or 255 (which is neither 1 nor 2), in which case your program behaves incorrectly.

Answer (score 17):

The `choice` command is not available everywhere. With newer Windows versions, the `set` command has the `/p` option you can get user input

```
SET /P variable=[promptString]
```

see `set /?` for more info

Answer (score 12):

Here a bit easier:

```
@echo off
set /p var=Are You Sure?[Y/N]: 
if %var%== Y goto ...
if not %var%== Y exit
```

or

```
@echo off
echo Are You Sure?[Y/N]
choice /c YN
if %errorlevel%==1 goto yes
if %errorlevel%==2 goto no
:yes
echo yes
goto :EOF
:no
echo no
```

Comment: after the Y put the command you want to happen. That's what the ... are for :)

Comment: I meant: `%errorlevel%` is always an integer value. See [here](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for documentation including an example.

Comment: Finally , somebody who understood the question..

Answer (score 3):

Here's my go-to method for a **yes/no** answer.

It's case-insensitive also.

This just checks for the errors given by the input and sets the `choice` variable to whatever you require so it can be used below in the code.

```
@echo off
choice /M "[Opt 1]  Do you want to continue [Yes/No]"
if errorlevel 255 (
  echo Error
  ) else if errorlevel 2 (
  set "YourChoice=will not"
  ) else if errorlevel 1 (
  set "YourChoice=will"
  ) else if errorlevel 0 (
  goto :EOF
  )
  echo %YourChoice%
  pause
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use 'Choice' command

```
@echo off
echo Sure?

CHOICE /C YN 

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto CONTINUE
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 goto END

:END
exit

:CONTINUE
echo hi
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

There are so many answers, but none of them seems to be simple and straight forward. This is the code I am using:

```
choice /M "Do you want to continue?"

if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
    ... run your code lines here
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the batch program to exit back to the prompt and not close the prompt (A.K.A cmd.exe) you can use "exit /b".

This may help.

```
set /p _sure="Are you sure?"
::The underscore is used to ensure that "sure" is not an enviroment
::varible
if /I NOT "_sure"=="y" (
::the /I makes it so you can
exit /b
) else (
::Any other modifications...
)
```

Or if you don't want to use as many lines...

```
Set /p _sure="Are you sure?"
if /I NOT "_sure"=="y" exit /b
::Any other modifications and commands.
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example which I use in a backup (.bat / batch) script on Windows 10, which allows me to have different options when making backups.

```
...

:choice
set /P c=Do you want to rsync the archives to someHost[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :syncthefiles
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :doonotsyncthefiles
goto :choice

:syncthefiles
echo rsync files to somewhere ...
bash -c "rsync -vaz /mnt/d/Archive/Backup/ user@host:/home/user/Backup/blabla/"
echo done

:doonotsyncthefiles
echo Backup Complete!

...
```

You can have as many as you need of these blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a UI confirmation.

With [yesnopopup.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/yesnopopup.bat)

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('yesnopopup.bat') do (
    set "result=%%#"
)

if /i result==no (
    echo user rejected the script
    exit /b 1
) 

echo continue

rem --- other commands --
```

the user will see the following and depending on the choice the script will continue:

[image]

with absolutely the same script you can use also [iexpYNbutton.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/iexpress/iexpYNButton.bat) which will produce similar popup.

With [buttons.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/ui.extensions/buttons.bat) you can try the following script:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('buttons.bat "Yep!" "Nope!" ') do (
    set "result=%%#"
)

if /i result==2 (
    echo user rejected the script
    exit /b 1
) 

echo continue

rem --- other commands --
```

and the user will see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way to make sure the testing and variables are correct during looping etc..

```
:: rem at the top of the script
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: choice example
CHOICE /C YNC /M "Continue? Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
If /I "[!errorlevel!]" NEQ "[1]" ( GOTO START_OVER )
```

Answer (score -1):

First, open the terminal.

Then, type

```
cd ~
touch .sure
chmod 700 .sure
```

Next, open .sure and paste this inside.

```
#!/bin/bash --init-file
PS1='> '
alias y='
    $1
    exit
'
alias n='Taskkill /IM %Terminal% /f'
echo ''
echo 'Are you sure? Answer y or n.'
echo ''
```

After that, close the file.

```
~/.sure ; ENTER COMMAND HERE
```

This will give you a prompt of are you sure before continuing the command.

Comment: Maybe in bash, but certainly not in batch.

Comment: Oh. I guess not. It only works for terminal commands not batch commands. Sorry for the false information.