# Batch "if" statement not working

Tags: batch-file, variables, if-statement

I seem to have a problem with my "if" statements. Currently after the pause in "start" the file just closes and nothing else happens. Chances are, I have no idea what I'm doing.

```
@echo off

set startnum=0
goto start

:start
pause
set startnum="!startnum!"+1
if "%startnum%"="%0%" goto fail
if "%startnum%"="%1%" goto success
goto start

:success
cls
echo It worked!
echo "%startnum%"
pause.
exit

:fail
cls
echo Failure
pause.
exit
```

Comment: What do you think `%0%` and `%1%` are?

Comment: Whoops, they are variables in that line of code. Even when I fix it, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first **IF** statement is preprocessed by `cmd.exe` to

```
if ""!startnum!"+1"="test.bat" goto fail
```

which is a completely invalid **IF** condition.

`cmd.exe` outputs a syntax error message because of `"="test.bat""` and exits batch file processing. This can be seen by [debugging the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

The solution is using right syntax for

- assigning a value to an environment variable,
- an arithmetic expression,
- and last but not least the **IF** condition itself.

The batch file code fixed:

```
@echo off

set "startnum=0"
goto Begin

:Begin
set /A startnum+=1
if "%startnum%" == "0" goto Fail
if "%startnum%" == "1" goto Success
goto Begin

:Success
cls
echo It worked!
echo "%startnum%"
pause
exit /B

:Fail
cls
echo Failure
pause
exit /B
```

It would be safe here to remove all double quotes on both **IF** conditions.

One more hint: Don't use the name of a command like **START** as label. It works, but it should be avoided in case of ever adding to batch file the command **START** and searching for either command or label.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains how to reference batch file arguments.
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`

Further read the answers on following questions:

- [Batch file comparison of variable with constant fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564)

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up getting it to completely work on my own after some more searching and thinking, but this is a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

First problem:

```
set startnum="!startnum!"+1
```

Evidently, you wish to add `1` to `startnum`.

Your `set` command would set `startnum` to `"!startnum!"+1`. Literally. To perform arithmetic, you need `set /a`.

```
set /A startnum="!startnum!"+1
```

well, this won't work as `"!startnum!` isn't numeric. Had you invoked `delayedexpansion` beforehand, then the value of `startnum` would have been substituted for `!startnum!` yielding `set /A startnum="0"+1` which makes more, but still not much sense.

```
set /A startnum=startnum+1
```

adds 1 to `startnum` - see `set /?` from the prompt for documentation.

```
set /A startnum+=1
```

would also add 1 to `startnum`.

Next problem.

```
if "%startnum%"="%0%" goto fail
```

Well, you appear to have found `lss` and all that gang. Problem is that the simple comparison operator is `==`, not `=`.

```
if "%startnum%"=="%0%" goto fail
```

Now - what will that do? It will compare **"***thecontentsofstartnum***"** to **"***thecontentsof0***"**. Since *both* of these arguments are quoted, batch will perform a *string* comparison. With a string comparison, **123** is *less* than **89** *because* `1` is less than `8`.

But - you are attempting an *equivalence*  comparison (`equ` as the operator may be used instead of `==`) so the preceding point is simply AAMOI.

The difficulty is `%0%` which you may believe attempts to extract the value of the variable `0` but actually it replaces `%0` with the value of the `0th` parameter to the batchfile, which is the batchfile name itself, so you get **"***batchfilename***%"** - probably not what you actually wanted.

```
if "%startnum%"=="0" goto fail
```

is the way to implement that test.