# Why does FOR /L in batch file not work as expected?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file:

```
:extract_stream
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('%media_info% "--output=%stream_count_string%" "%file%"') DO SET /A "stream_type_total=%%A"

SET /A "stream_count=1"

FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A IN ('%media_info% "--output=%format_string%" "%file%"') DO (
    SET /A "id=%%A-1"
    SET "title=%%B"
    SET "codec=%%C"
    SET "language=%%D"

    REM SET "id=!id:~1!"
    SET "title=!title:~1!"
    SET "codec=!codec:~1!"
    SET "language=!language:~1!"

    IF NOT DEFINED language SET "language=English"
    REM IF "!codec!" EQU "V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC" SET "language="

    SET stream_obj[!stream_count!].id=!id!

    ECHO ID:!id! Title=!title!, Codec=!codec!, Lamguage=!language!

    SET /A "stream_count+=1"
)
(  ENDLOCAL
    FOR /L  %%A IN (1,1,%stream_type_total%) DO (
        CALL SET "stream_obj[%%A].id=%stream_obj[%%A].id%"
    )
)
GOTO:EOF
```

But I cannot get `%%A` in `FOR /L` loop working as expected.

If I use a number like `1` instead of `%%A`, it works just fine.

```
SET "stream_obj[1].id=%stream_obj[1].id%"
```

But the command line in `FOR /L` loop is not working with:

```
SET "stream_obj[%%A].id=%stream_obj[%%A].id%"
```

Why?

When I checked with `echo`, it cut the line odd at the equal sign `=`. So I don't know if it has something to do with that.

Comment: In the `CALL SET "stream_obj[%%A].id=%stream_obj[%%A].id%"` the part  `%stream_obj[%%A].id%"` is always empty, as the percent expansion tries to find a variable named `stream_obj[%%A].id`, the expansion of `%%A` is later than the percent expansion.  But even if you double the percent signs, it will fail, as the ENDLOCAL has removed the variables already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an **arithmetic expression** to assign a value to an environment variable. There is usually no reason to do so. Just use  `SET "stream_type_total=%%A"` without `/A`.

There should be a space between command `GOTO` and its first argument `:EOF`.

But the main problem is the command block:

```
(  ENDLOCAL
    FOR /L  %%A IN (1,1,%stream_type_total%) DO (
        CALL SET "stream_obj[%%A].id=%stream_obj[%%A].id%"
    )
)
```

The command **ENDLOCAL** does not only restore previous state of delayed environment variable expansion, it discards also the currently active environment variables list and restores previous list of environment variables. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

So the environment variable `stream_type_total` as well as all `stream_obj[x].id` environment variables do not exist anymore after this command.

I suggest to modify this command block to:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%stream_type_total%) DO CALL SET "stream_obj[%%A].id=%stream_obj[%%A].id%"
ENDLOCAL
```

Now the **FOR** loop should work as expected.

But please note that even with this change the modified `stream_obj[x].id` environment variables do not exist anymore after command **ENDLOCAL**.

So better would be to avoid usage of **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** in this subroutine completely like with using this code:

```
:extract_stream
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('%media_info% "--output=%stream_count_string%" "%file%"') DO SET "stream_type_total=%%A"

SET "stream_count=1"

FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A IN ('%media_info% "--output=%format_string%" "%file%"') DO (
    SET /A "id=%%A-1"
    SET "title=%%B"
    SET "codec=%%C"
    SET "language=%%D"

    REM SET "id=!id:~1!"
    CALL SET "title=%%title:~1%%"
    CALL SET "codec=%%codec:~1%%"
    IF DEFINED language CALL SET "language=%%language:~1%%"

    IF NOT DEFINED language SET "language=English"
    REM IF "!codec!" EQU "V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC" SET "language="

    CALL SET "stream_obj[%%stream_count%%].id=%%id%%"

    CALL ECHO ID:%%id%% Title=%%title%%, Codec=%%codec%%, Language=%%language%%

    SET /A "stream_count+=1"
)

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%stream_type_total%) DO CALL SET "stream_obj[%%A].id=%stream_obj[%%A].id%"
GOTO :EOF
```

The commands commented out with command **REM** are **not** modified in code above.

Another solution would be using one more subroutine:

```
:extract_stream
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('%media_info% "--output=%stream_count_string%" "%file%"') DO SET "stream_type_total=%%A"

SET "stream_count=1"

FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A IN ('%media_info% "--output=%format_string%" "%file%"') DO CALL :UpdateVariables "%%~A" "%%~B" "%%~C" "%%~D"

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%stream_type_total%) DO CALL SET "stream_obj[%%A].id=%stream_obj[%%A].id%"
GOTO :EOF

:UpdateVariables
SET /A "id=%~1-1"
SET "title=%~2"
SET "codec=%~3"
SET "language=%~4"

REM SET "id=%id:~1%"
SET "title=%title:~1%"
SET "codec=%codec:~1%"
IF DEFINED language SET "language=%language:~1%"

IF NOT DEFINED language SET "language=English"
REM IF "%codec%" == "V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC" SET "language="

SET "stream_obj[%stream_count%].id=%id%"

ECHO ID:%id% Title=%title%, Codec=%codec%, Language=%language%

SET /A "stream_count+=1"
GOTO :EOF
```

The commands commented out with command **REM** are modified in code above too.

One last hint: Don't use comparison operator `EQU` on comparing two strings. This operator is designed for comparing 32-bit signed integer values and not for string comparisons. Read the answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) for details about comparing strings or integer values with command **IF**.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get more than one value out of a setlocal scope, you can't use a loop/call the way you tried.

I see two different solutions.
1) Rescue one value in each loop by leaving the setlocal scope and reenter it.
But then you also lose all other variables like stream_count

2) Use a `endlocal` block with one aggregated variable for all your vars to resuce.
Like

set "rescue=%stream_obj[1].id%:%stream_obj[2].id%:%stream_obj[3].id%"

See also
[exit function and preserve variable over endlocal barrier](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6496&p=41929#p41929)
[Macro to return multiple variables across endlocal barriers](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5473)