# How do I stop my batch file from doing commands when I'm using the set statement?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a chatbot.

This is my script:

```
:start
set /p message=
if %message%==Hello echo Hi!
goto start
```

But if I try to type something in like.. `hello = world`, it closes. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Please read the long answers on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) and [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) if you are interested in why the command line `if %message%==Hello echo Hi!` fails with a string entered containing a space or one of these characters ``"&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|>``. Double quoting the compared strings is helpful with exception of user entered string contains one or more `"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if /i "%message%"=="Hello world" echo Hi!
```

Quote both sides of the comparison-operator. Note that `/i` makes the test case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if the message starts with `hello` then test `%message:~0,5%`

```
@echo off
:start
cls
set /p "message=type something: "
if /i "%message:~0,5%"=="Hello" echo Hi!
goto start
```

So by typing `hello world` it will detect the characters 0 - 5 being `hello`, `/i` makes it case insensitive as mentioned by **@magoo**

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already been answered succinctly by Magoo, this is just an example to show a way of detecting if the input string contained the case insensitive string `hello`:

```bat
If /I Not "%message%"=="%message:hello=%" Echo Hi!
```