# How to find substring returned from PowerShell function with command SET in batch file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, substring

I've called .ps1 function in batch file and assigned the result to `$Value` variable:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\test.ps1 -TargetGroupArn "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:570226278193:targetgroup/whocms-uat/cc28ab2765d2503c" -TargetId "i-01fab6896b4efa925" -state "healthy" -timeout 240') do Set "$Value=%%a"
```

When checked with echo it prints the correct result: `09/13/2018 16:34:34 : healthy`

```
Echo Value received from PowerShell : %$Value%
```

But I am not able to check if the result contains substring:

```
set str1=%Value%
if not x%str1:healthy=%==x%str1% echo It contains healthy
```

Comment: You need to surround your string comparisons in double quotes to protect spaces and special characters. `if not "x%str1:healthy=%"=="x%str1%" echo It contains healthy`

Comment: Why can you not use `-match "healthy"` in your PowerShell command, instead of running it in a `For` loop, saving the output as a variable, then expanding/replacing the string in the variable to determine if it was part of the output?

Comment: Should also note that you missed using the dollar symbol with your variable name in the`set` command.

Comment: With surrounding quotes the leading `x` is no longer necessary to be safe against empty values...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite simple:

```
if not "%$Value:healthy=%" == "%$Value%" echo It contains healthy
```

The double quotes around the two string arguments between the operator `==` results in interpreting everything between `"` as literal characters by **IF**. Otherwise a space inside value string is interpreted as argument separator.

**IF** includes the double quotes on comparing the two strings. This means on using `"..."` for one argument, `"..."` must be also used on other argument as otherwise the two compared strings are never equal.

For even more details on how **IF** compares strings or integers see the answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564).

PS: `$` has no special meaning for Windows command processor on being used in an environment variable name. It is interpreted as literal character like a letter.