# How to loop a command inside a "for" command?

Tags: batch-file, parameters

I want the batch file to move files %3 number of times, how can I accomplish this?

%1 is the source folder
%2 is the destination folder
%3 is the number of files
%4 is the filter.
This is the best I could come up with but it doesn't seem to work consistently.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set movedFiles=0
if [%4] EQU [] goto regular
:special
for /R  "%1" %%G in (%4) do (
    echo moving "%4"... "%%G"
    move /Y "%%G" "%2"
    set /a movedFiles+="1"
    if !movedFiles! EQU %3 GOTO endOfCopy
)
GOTO endOfCopy
:regular
for /R  "%1" %%G in (*) do (
    echo moving... "%%G"
    move /Y "%%G" "%2"
    set /a movedFiles+="1"
    if !movedFiles! EQU %3 GOTO endOfCopy
)
:endOfCopy
echo Done, %movedFiles% files Where copied successfully
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work consistently" - what exactly does it do?

Comment: Well, the %3 part does nothing. It moves the files alright, but doesn't consider %3.

Comment: seems to work fine for me (and consistent).

Comment: So I didn't mess something up? Didn't expect that. Have any idea what might be the cause of my problem?

Comment: My apologies, I'm a newbie here as it might appear.

Comment: To get an idea what might cause your problem, you will have to tell us *what* problem you have. Please edit your question accordingly (how exactly are you executing the script and what exactly happens that you didn't expect?).

Comment: No problem, so now we have that covered.. what do you get when you `echo %3`

Comment: `EQU` is the operator two compare two 32-bit signed integer values. It works also for string comparisons because of `cmd.exe` runs automatically a string comparison on one of the two operands cannot be successfully converted from a string to an integer value. `[` and `]` which do not have any special meaning and are therefore interpreted like `abcd` results in operands being never valid integers. So don't use `EQU` to compare case-sensitive two strings, use the operator `==` which is designed for string comparisons and makes always a string comparison even if both strings represent integers.

Comment: So use `if "%~4" == ""` instead of `if [%4] EQU []` because of `"` has a special meaning as it results in interpreting everything between the double quotes as literal character with exception of `%` and `!` if delayed expansion is enabled. See also [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564). Wrong is also `"%1"` and correct would be `"%~1"`. Wrong is `"%2" because of correct is `"%~2"` as well as `"%4"` which should be `"%~4"`. Wrong is `set /a movedFiles+="1"` and correct is `set /a movedFiles+=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change your code a little, *(and in the meantime see if it fixes your issue)*:

```bat
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If "%~4"=="" (Call :StartMove %* "*") Else Call :StartMove %*
Pause & GoTo :EOF

:StartMove
Set "Moved=0" & For /R "%~1" %%A In ("%~4") Do (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If !Moved! Equ %3 (EndLocal & Set "Moved=%Moved%" & GoTo EndMessage)
    Echo ...Moving "%%A" & Move /Y "%%A" "%~2" >Nul 2>&1 && Set /A Moved +=1)

:EndMessage
Echo Done, %Moved% files were copied successfully & EndLocal & Exit /B
```

Please note that this code, *like yours*, does not verify input parameters, *(whether they exist, are of the correct type, in the correct order etc)*, I'd suggest you implement something to do so, moving forward. Even adding something as simple as the following would be a start:

```bat
If Not Exist "%~1\" Exit /B
If Not Exist "%~2\" Exit /B
If "%~3"=="" Exit /B
```