# Batch program is skipping GOTO blocks

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing something in BATCH and I need to use GOTO's but instead of going to the correct GOTO it goes to the next label/class rather then the right one.

I've tried using it without a colon but still can't get a solution.

```
@echo off 
title Nexus Generator
color 0a 
goto :signin  

:signin
echo =====================================
echo Welcome to NEXUS GENERATOR!
echo Please enter your KEY!
echo =====================================
set /p id="Enter Key: "
if %id% == "Test" then goto :signedin else goto :error

:error
echo uh lol

:signedin
cls
echo lol
pause >nul
```

I expect that when TEST is entered it will go to signedin, and when anything else is entered it will go to error.

Comment: The strings on both sides of the comparison operator must match to gain a `True` condition, so you need to quote the %variable%. `if /i` makes the comparison case-insensitive

Comment: So it would go like this instead?
if /i %id% == "Test" then goto %signedin% else goto %error%

Comment: I recommend to read the answers on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) and [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564).

Comment: your variable needs to be quoted as well. `if "%id%" == "Test" goto..` and there is no `then` function in batch.

Comment: `if "%id%" == "Test"  (goto :signedin) else (goto :error)` **then** is seen as an executable with arguments `goto :signedin else goto :error`. Without the **then** the instruction executed is `goto :signedin else goto :error` which *should* action the first `goto` and ignore the remainder. Parenthesising the `goto destination` clauses allows `cmd` to successfully resolve the ambiguous syntax.

Comment: Simple solution: just write `if /I "%id%" == "Test" goto :sugnedin`, because if the condition is not fulfilled, execution continues at section `:error` anyway; nevertheless, type `if /?` and read the help text...

Answer (score 1):

- You need compare some "in quotes" with some "in quotes" too,
- goto :some place to avoid next line to be executed, like goto :eof

```bat
@echo off 

color 0a
title Nexus Generator

echo/=====================================
echo/Welcome to NEXUS GENERATOR^!
echo/Please enter your KEY^!
echo/=====================================

set /p "id=Enter Key: "
if /i "%id%" == "test" goto :signedin

:error
echo/uh lol
goto :eof

:signedin
cls 
echo/lol 
pause >nul
```

in one short version:

```bat
@echo off & color 0a 
title Nexus Generator
echo/=====================================
echo/Welcome to NEXUS GENERATOR^!
echo/Please enter your KEY^!
echo/=====================================
set /p "id=Enter Key: "
echo/%id%|findstr /lic:"test" 2>nul && goto :signedin
:error
echo/uh lol & goto :eof
:signedin
cls & echo/lol & pause >nul
```

Comment: When using this code, putting in something other then TEST crashed the program.

Comment: Still crashing the program if I enter something other then TEST.

Comment: I see, replace == to equ in if,, thank you for real time reply!

Comment: Followed your instructions and still crashing?

Comment: Add some character to var, so, if user accidentally pres one key not characters, like one operator or something.  Any suggest, I'm here, thank you! sorry my English.

Comment: `set /p` replaces the value (or leaves it unchanged if user just presses ENTER) - it does not concatenate. So a preset makes no sense in this case. And especially not a space - which you remove anyway with `%id: =%` (which is also not needed and possibly even harmful)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you only have 2 results you want to `goto`, I would say you do not need the else statement as the `goto` will only occur if the `if` statement matches, else it will simply fall through to the error. We however need to test each side of the operator to be equal. Currently you are testing `Test == "Test"`. Note the one is quoted and the other not and you want to have an exact match, therefore you need to double quote your variable. `"%id%"=="Test"`:

```
@echo off 
title Nexus Generator
color 0a 
goto :signin  

:signin
echo =====================================
echo Welcome to NEXUS GENERATOR!
echo Please enter your KEY!
echo =====================================
set /p id="Enter Key: "
if /i "%id%" == "Test" goto :signedin

echo Oops, you entered "%id%" instead of "Test"
goto :eof

:signedin
cls
echo You're now signed in!!
pause >nul
```

That said, I prefer not using `goto` statements unless completely needed, so we can just run code blocks after the `if` and `else` statements:

```
@echo off 
title Nexus Generator
color 0a 
goto :signin  

:signin
echo =====================================
echo Welcome to NEXUS GENERATOR!
echo Please enter your KEY!
echo =====================================
set /p id="Enter Key: "
if /i "%id%" == "Test" (
      cls
      echo You're now signed in!!
  ) else (
      cls
      echo Oops, you entered "%id%" instead of "Test"
)
pause >nul
```