# Looping through input parameter in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file where I want to concatinate folders to the `PATH` variable.
The folders should be given to the batch via parameter.

I would call the file like this:

> set_path.bat "\Folder1;\Folder2;\Folder3"

Right now I have this:

```
set FOLDERS=%1
set FOLDERS=%FOLDERS:"=%

:NextItem
if [%FOLDERS%] == [] goto EOF

FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a IN (%FOLDERS%) DO 
(
echo %%a
set "FOLDERS=%%b"
)

goto NextItem

:EOF
```

For now it's just supposed to echo the folder names.
What I expect as result is

> \Folder1
>   \Folder2
>   \Folder3

However if I try this I can the error after the `set FOLDERS=\Folder1,\Folder2`:

*"\Folder2]" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet
 werden.*

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: If you want to concatenate a value to PATH variable, use this form: `set "PATH=%PATH%;new value"`. If the value is given in the first parameter enclosed in quotes, use this: `set "PATH=%PATH%;%~1"`

Comment: @Aacini yes I know but I want to concat the PATH variable not with Folder1 Folder2 Folder3 but with C:\Temp\Folder1 C:\Temp\Folder2 etc. (just as an example). However the folders needs to come over the parameter like I wrote. So the issue is not really setting the PATH but rather seperating the strings.

Comment: Then you should explain _that_ in the question. Your problem is not related to PATH variable at all. I suggest you to entirely rewrite the question and change the title...  BTW in order to solve your problem, change the FOR command to this: `FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a IN ("%FOLDERS%") DO (`, that is, enclose FOLDERS variable in quotes and place the left paren in the same line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest following batch file code:

```
@echo off
set "Folders=%~1"

:NextFolderPath
for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%I in ("%Folders%") do (
    echo %%I
    set "Folders=%%J"
    if defined Folders goto NextFolderPath
)
```

The string assigned to environment variable `Folders` is `\Folder1;\Folder2;\Folder3` on running this batch file with `"\Folder1;\Folder2;\Folder3"` as first and only argument string. The double quotes around argument string are removed by Windows command processor because of using `%~1` instead of `%1`. This behavior is explained by the help output on running in a command prompt window `call /?`.

The command **FOR** is used to split up the **string** assigned currently to environment variable `Folders` enclosed in double quotes.

The string with the list of semicolon separated folder paths is split up into two substrings (tokens) because of `tokens=1* delims=;`. The first `;` separated string is always assigned to specified loop variable `I`. As this string never begins with a semicolon because of the semicolon is the delimiter, the default `eol=;` does not really matter here. The second string being everything after one or more semicolons after first folder path string is assigned to next loop variable `J` according to [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table.

The folder path string assigned to loop variable `I` is just output. The remaining folder paths are assigned again to environment variable `Folders` which is now either with one folder path less as before or is not defined anymore at all because of `Folders` contained on current iteration of the loop just one folder name.

The command **FOR** is executed once again on environment variable `Folders` still defined because of one or more folder paths still to process. Otherwise the batch file processing ends with reaching end of batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

See also [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564) I recommend to avoid the definition of label `:EOF` in future. I use as label at end of a batch file `:EndBatch` if I don't want to use `goto :EOF`.

For string comparisons it is advisable to use `if "%FOLDERS%" == ""`, i.e. enclose the two compared strings on both sides in double quotes, whereby the string value assigned to environment variable `FOLDERS` should not contain one or more `"` in which case this string comparison would fail. For details on string comparisons with command **IF** see my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564).

`if [%FOLDERS%] == []` is in general not good because of the square brackets have no special meaning in comparison to `"`. `[` and `]` are interpreted by Windows command processor on processing and executing the **IF** condition command line like the letters `X` and `Y`. But `"` has a special meaning because all characters, except `%` and with enabled [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) also `!`, are interpreted inside a double quoted argument string as literal characters including the command operators `&`, `&&` and `||` as well as the redirection operators  `<`, `>`, `>>` and `|` and the round brackets `(` and `)`.

See also [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)