# How should I use spaces in if in batch files

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use spaces in the following command

```
if /I %clubeligaNOS% == Rio Ave goto Rio Ave
```

but if I write `Rio Ave`, instead of going to `:Rio Ave` it closes the program, it works if I just use Rio. If anyone knows how to use spaces in this please help

(I've already tried quotes "")

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: You cannot have a label with spaces so change `:Rio Ave` to `:RioAve`, and your command should be, `if /I "%clubeligaNOS%" == "Rio Ave" goto RioAve`. That assumes you have not omitted any other important information, and that everything else in your script up to that point is correct.

Comment: I recommend reading my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) which explains very detailed how to do a __string__ comparison with command __IF__ in a batch file.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `if /I %clubeligaNOS% == Rio Ave goto Rio Ave`
use `if /I %clubeligaNOS% == "Rio Ave" goto x`
the reason being batch (most languages) doesn't like spaces in variable/function names so if you put quotes it says that is one thing instead of 2

Comment: ImaGonnaDie, please check out my comment below the question itself, to see the correct syntax and proper advice for solving the issue.