# Why doesn't IF branch properly?

Tags: cmd

I already asked this in [SS64](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=10170#p10170).

I'm trying to use IF DEFINED  to control branching, but it doesn't work. I will start with an example

```
setLocal
if defined _var (
::  _var is NOT defined, so the next line should not be executed
    if %_var%=="test" echo %_var% is defined
)
endLocal
```

Processing stops when it hits the ECHO statement and exits with "echo was unexpected at this time." error message.
The problem is that the nested IF statement is being executed, and it *shouldn't* be because _var is not defined. How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Shane.

Comment: Because using `::` for a comment can only be done outside of a code block defined by parenthesis.  Instead use `REM `.  `::` is an over-loaded label that will not print even if you leave `ECHO ON` but it does not play nice with parenthesis, and the script will throw errors snd evaluate lines it should not be able to reach that are inside parenthesis when `::` is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem you have is just that you did not match the if statement correctly. To explain, see the following example.

```
if a == "a"..
```

vs

```
if "a"=="a"..
```

So in you example you were trying to match:

```
if test=="test"..
```

The reason we use double quotes on both sides of the variable is to ensure we eliminate any possible whitespace which might become part of the values you are testing.

So this version should be fine. I added the `/i` switch to match `test` case insensitive, so it will match `test` in any case combination. `TesT`, `tEst`, `TEST`, `test` etc.:

```
setLocal
set /p "_var=Enter Variable name: "
set "_var=%_var:"=%"
if defined _var (
:# rem _var is NOT defined, so the next line should not be executed
    if /i "%_var%"=="test" echo %_var% is defined
)
endLocal
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with this small code block.

The first issue is using an invalid label with `::` to write a comment inside a command block starting with `(` and ending matching with `)`. A label is not allowed inside a command block. A line starting with `:` after 0 or more spaces/tabs results in undefined behavior on execution of the command block. Undefined behavior means it can work by chance, but it can also fail by chance. The execution behavior is undefined.

The **command** for a comment is **REM**. Run in a command prompt window `rem /?` for help on this command.

Please note that **REM** is a **command** and for that reason a comment line with **REM** is parsed by Windows command processor like any other command line which is important on comment line contains `%variable%` or operators like `&|<>`. So be careful on what is written in comment text.

---

The second issue is that the comment itself is not correct.

> _var is NOT defined, so the next line should not be executed

This comment is wrong because the environment variable `_var` is definitely defined on `cmd.exe` reaching this line after execution of the command `if defined _var` with a positive result.

---

The third issue is that `if %_var%=="test"` is syntactically not 100% correct. There are missing the spaces around the comparison operator `==`. But this syntax error is automatically detected by `cmd.exe` on processing the batch file with automatic correction by inserting the two missing spaces around operator `==`. This can be seen on [debugging the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

---

The fourth issue is that **IF** compares two strings always with including the double quotes on string comparison. So on usage of `if %_var%=="test"` or syntactically correct `if %var% == "test"` the condition is only true if assigned to environment variable `_var` is the string `"test"` with the double quotes. This string comparison evaluates to false in all other cases on `_var` defined if not resulting in a syntax error before, see next issue.

Please read my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) explaining very detailed how a string comparison is done by command **IF**.

---

The fifth issue is that Windows command processor parses the entire command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` before executing the command **IF**.

The inner **IF** without environment variable `_var` defined results on parsing the command block in the line:

```
if =="test" echo is defined
```

`cmd.exe` detects a serious syntax error on this command line and exits batch file processing because of this syntax error before executing the outer **IF** condition.

One solution would be enclosing `%var%` in double quotes, i.e. use in batch file:

```
if "%_var%" == "test" echo %_var% is defined
```

This **IF** command line is correct if the environment variable `_var` is not defined on parsing the command block.

But this solution does not work if `_var` is defined and contains one or more `"` because of the double quotes result again in an invalid syntax for command line with command **IF**.

Further `echo` does not result in printing the value of the environment variable `_var` if the string assigned to the environment variable contains one of these characters `&|<>`. Well, `echo` is not executed in this case as the string comparison evaluates to false.

Therefore a better solution is enabling [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and referencing the value of environment variable `_var` with delayed environment variable expansion to avoid that the value of this environment variable modifies the command line to execute by `cmd.exe` after parsing entire command block.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined _var (
    rem  _var is defined, so the next line should be executed.
    if "!_var!" == "test" echo _var is defined with !_var!.
)
endlocal
```

The command extensions must be also enabled because otherwise `if defined` would not be supported by command **IF**. The command extensions are by default enabled, but it is better to write a batch file with no dependency on settings or defaults defined outside of the batch file as far as possible.

Well, the `echo` command could be also written with:

```
echo _var is defined with test.
```

It is not possible that `echo` prints here something other than `test` on using `!_var!`.

Another solution is to avoid the usage of a command block and make sure that the string value assigned to environment variable `_var` does not contain any `"` and output the value of this environment variable enclosed in double quotes to avoid that `&|<>` affect the execution of `echo` command line.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not defined _var goto Label

rem _var is defined, so the next line should be executed.
rem Remove all double quotes from string value of environment variable.
rem It is important to use double quotes around argument string of the
rem command SET as otherwise a string with "&|<>" would be not correct
rem assigned to the environment variable.

set "_var=%_var:"=%"

rem It could happen that _var is not defined anymore. But in this case
rem it is no problem anymore that cmd.exe replaces all %var% by nothing
rem on entire command line before executing the IF condition as the
rem remaining commands on this command line with enclosing the string
rem value of _var in double quotes is always syntactically correct even
rem on string value containing one or more of the operators "&|<>".

if /I "%_var%" == "test" echo _var is defined with "%_var%".

:Label
endlocal
```

The string comparison is done here case-insensitive.

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))

It must be always made sure that a user input string or a string passed to the batch file as argument or a string determined by the batch file itself for example from a file/folder name/path is enclosed in double quotes and does itself not contain double quotes for being correct processed by the batch file. While the characters `|<>` are not allowed in a file/folder name, `&` is allowed in a file/folder name and results in many batch files on being interpreted as AND operator on file/folder string not enclosed in double quotes, even on simply `echo`ing the file/folder name.

See also the Microsoft documentation page [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

---

It is very important to understand on writing a batch file [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) It must be always taken into account how a command line finally looks on execution with environment variable references expanded during parsing phase of a command line or an entire command block. The finally executed command line after parsing must be of valid syntax or `cmd.exe` exits batch file processing.