# Removing file in windows batch script not working

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a batch script for trimming 25 seconds from the beginning of all mp4 files in a folder. The batch script is located in the same folder as the files, and there is a folder called `trimmed` in the same folder. This is my script so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

:promptdel
set /p delorig=Delete original file (default no)? [Y/N]: 

if not defined delorig (
  set delorig=N
)

set "vartwo="&for /f "delims=YNyn" %%i in ("%delorig%") do set vartwo=%%i

if defined vartwo (
  echo Please state Y or N!
  goto :promptdel
)

for %%a in ("*.mp4") do (
  echo Starting %%a

  rem "Need to rename since file names may contain whitespaces"
  ren "%%a" "working.mp4"
  ffmpeg -loglevel panic -hide_banner -i "working.mp4" -ss 00:00:25.000 -c:v copy -c:a copy "trimmed\%%a"
  ren "working.mp4" "%%a"

  echo %delorig%
  if %delorig% == "Y" (del "%%a" /f /q)
  if %delorig% == "y" (del "%%a" /f /q)

  echo %%a finished!
)

pause
```

My problem is that the original file does not get removed regardless of if I input y/Y or n/N. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quoted one side of the equation... but not the other. Change

```
  if %delorig% == "Y" (del "%%a" /f /q)
  if %delorig% == "y" (del "%%a" /f /q)
```

to

```
  if "%delorig%"=="Y" (del "%%a" /f /q)
  if "%delorig%"=="y" (del "%%a" /f /q)
```

or better yet... do this to make the comparison case-insensitive.

```
if /i "%delorig%"=="Y" del "%%a" /f /q
```

Comment: There are the spaces left and right to `==` missing in your code. They are important for 100% syntactically correct code as explained in my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564). Windows command processor automatically detects usually (depends on compared strings) that syntax error and automatically corrects the lines and inserts the missing spaces around the operator argument `==`, but it is nevertheless better to write the code 100% correct in the batch file instead of depending on automatic correction.

Comment: The applied automatic correction can be seen on creating a batch file with `if "hello"=="world" echo !` as first line and `@pause` as second line and executing this batch file. Output is by `cmd.exe` the line `if "hello" == "world" echo !`. So Windows command processor inserted the missing spaces around operator argument `==` before execution of the __IF__ command line. BTW: The usage of spaces around `==` in batch file makes the code also easier to read in my opinion, especially on not using a text editor with syntax highlighting of batch files.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to include this answer, as I believe that the fix isn't technically the best way to deal with the issue you are having.

The best way would be to use the `choice` command, instead of allowing uncontrolled input data via `set /p`.

It is also, to my knowledge, not necessary to change a name containing spaces, especially as your `ffmpeg` code is already using doublequoted filenames.

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /T 10 /D N /M "Delete original file [default No]" 
Set "delorig=%ErrorLevel%" 
For %%G In ("*.mp4") Do (Echo Starting %%G
    "ffmpeg.exe" -loglevel panic -hide_banner -i "%%G" -ss 00:00:25.000 -c:v copy -c:a copy "trimmed\%%G"
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 If %delorig% Equ 1 Del /F/Q "%%G"
    Echo %%G finished!)
Pause
```

*Please note, that I have included the extension for `ffmpeg` to prevent accidental modification of `%PATHEXT%` from not running `.EXE` files. I would also suggest, if known/possible, that you use the full path to `ffmpeg.exe`, to ensure that possible `%PATH%`/directory/registry changes don't prevent it from being run, (as the code has not explicitly set a current directory). Additionally the code does not first ensure that a directory named `trimmed` exists in the current directory, so if `ffmpeg` cannot create it itself, you should probably perform a check, and/or create it first.*