# How to test equality between variable and string in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to check whether the first argument passed to the file is `python`, if so I would like to go to a particular block. It feels like I'm misunderstanding something about the way batch files test for equality.

```
@echo off
IF ("%1"=="python") (GOTO py) ELSE (echo %1)

GOTO end
:py
IF ("%2"=="") (echo ) ELSE (.\Programs\Anaconda\condabin\conda.bat activate %2)
.\Programs\Anaconda\python
GOTO end
:nextpy

:end
```

The output of this file when called `D:>launcher.bat python` is:

```
python
```

I expect it to instead open a python shell.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `if /?` and read the output help for the command __IF__. Next run also `call /?` as read about `%1` and `%~1` to reference fist argument of a batch file which could be already in double quotes, but could be also without double quotes. Then read my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) explaining very detailed how a string comparison is done by __IF__ respectively Windows command processor.

Comment: I suggest to modify `IF ("%1"=="python") (GOTO py) ELSE (echo %1)` to `IF /I "%~1" == "python" (GOTO py) ELSE (echo(%1)` with looking on where `(` and `)` are used and where are space characters placed on this command line. The __ELSE__ branch could be also just `ELSE echo(%1`. I suggest `IF not "%~2" == "" .\Programs\Anaconda\condabin\conda.bat activate %2` for the second __IF__ condition. See also DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Comment: `(` between `echo` and `%1` makes sure that echo status is not output by Windows command processor if the batch file is called without any argument string.

Comment: just to clarify: `("%1"` will never be equal to `"python")` the parentheses here are part of the strings, not part of any syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all the `goto` statements as you can run the code inside of the parenthesized code blocks. but your main problem is the fact that you placed `if` statements inside parenthesis:

Here is an example of how to run the code inside of the blocks instead of using `goto`

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" echo You have not added any parameters.
if /i "%~1"=="python" (
  if not "%~2"=="" (
          echo .\Programs\Anaconda\condabin\conda.bat activate %~2
   ) else (
          echo empty parameter "%%2"
      )
   ) else (
          if /i "%~1"=="perl" (
          echo you chose perl
   )
)
```

Note that I used the `/I` switch with the `if` statement simply to match case insensitive words. So it will accept `PYTHON` `PyThoN` `python` etc.