# Batch file crashing seemingly randomly at start of for-Loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, debugging, crash

I'm trying to create a batch-File to automate some processes, but as of now, it crashes as soon as it reaches this line

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (...)
```

I've tried debugging as much as I could, but only managed to pinpoint the error down to this part.
Here's the code leading up to this line:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
.
.
.
set /p amount="[1] One/[2] Multiple "
if /i "%amount:~,1%" EQU "1" goto one
if /i "%amount:~,1%" EQU "2" goto multiple
:multiple
set /a i=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (..\multiple.txt) do (
    set /a i+=1
    set array[!i!]=%%a
)
set /a b=1
echo %i% systems have been detected
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
    echo System !b!: IP: !array[%%i]!
    set /a b+=1
)
echo.
echo Please confirm that the input is correct and all systems have been reset to their factory default
set /p confirm="[O]kay/[E]xit "
if /i "%confirm:~,1%" EQU "O" echo Okay
if /i "%confirm:~,1%" EQU "E" goto exit
echo.
echo What type of system are you trying to set up?
echo [0] CPU-Blade
echo [1] GPU-Blade
echo [2] Optic Server
echo [3] Tool Host
echo [4] Provisioning Server
echo [5] Customer Host
echo [6] Control PC
echo [7] Gateway
echo [8] Cluster File Server
echo [9] Storage Expansion Shelf
set /p system="[0]/[1]/[2]/[3]/[4]/[5]/[6]/[7]/[8]/[9] "
set /a b=1
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
    echo Resetting Chassis Intrusion for System !b!: !array[%%i]!...
```

I've thought that maybe the for-Loop executed prior to the crashing one might have some issues with them both using the `%%i`, so I tried temporarily changing that to `%%e`, with no success.
I also copied another instance of this loop:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
    echo System !b!: IP: !array[%%i]!
    set /a b+=1
)
pause
```

Right before the crashing loop, but it executed with no problems. I'm at a complete loss right now, any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (..\multiple.txt) do (` supposed to do? Are you supposed to be reading lines from the file? Please try a test batch file using just `@(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (..\multiple.txt) do @echo=%%a) & pause` to check that it is doing what it is supposed to be doing. If it is not please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information for that particular command. I would also advise you to stop using `set /p` in situations which the `choice` command was designed to handle, (`choice /?` for more info).

Comment: @Compo thanks for the info about choice, I'll be implementing that!
The for-Loop in question is simply reading lines from the file(IP Addresses to be exact, 1 address per line with no spaces anywhere). I've created this and the loop after that in a separate test batch file to confirm it's doing what it's supposed to.
As far as I'm aware, everything in the code I posted is working as intended, up until it crashes on the third for-Loop. Which confuses me, since I've tested every part leading up to it, and there doesn't seem to be anything obvious wrong.

Comment: Did you test it using the single line replacement batch file I suggested? Normally I'd use, `For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("..\multiple.txt") Do (`, but for the purposes of showing you the reason I mentioned it, what happens if you change yours to `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("..\multiple.txt") do (`, or `for /F "delims=" %%a in (..\multiple.txt) do (`? Essentially, if you're using `UseBackQ` double-quote the file, if you don't want to double-quote the file, remove the `UseBackQ`, you're currently doing both, which to me looks wrong!

Comment: @Compo thanks for the explanation. I have tried using both examples you provided, but it still crashes on the last for-Loop

Comment: I am not cotinuing to play guessing games, create two batch files `test1.cmd` and `test2.cmd` and run them from the same location and in the same way as the one you submitted. `test1.cmd` : `@(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (..\multiple.txt) do @echo=%%a) & pause`, and `test2.cmd` : `@(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("..\multiple.txt") do @echo=%%a) & pause`. What is the output from each?

Comment: A batch file does not crash. A batch file is a simple text file with code which needs to be interpreted by an executable which is `cmd.exe` for a file with file extension `.bat` or `.cmd`. The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` does not crash on processing a batch file. It exits processing a batch file on detecting a serious syntax error making it impossible to continue processing the batch file. That error message can be seen on [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) and also which command line or which command block is responsible for the processing exit.

Comment: I recommend to read my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) It is no good idea to use `set /P` for user prompts on which the user has to press a key to make a choice of several offered options. There is the command `choice` for choice menus. See also DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Comment: I suggest further reading my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564). It explains very detailed how a string comparison is done by `cmd.exe` and why the string comparison operator `==` should be used for string comparisons and not the comparison operator `EQU`. The comparison operator `EQU` is designed primary for an integer comparison on equality and only results in doing a string comparison if `cmd.exe` fails to convert one of the two operands successfully to a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: BTW: You make coding work easier for yourself on using meaningful variable names. I recommend to replace `i` (the environment variable `i`) with `LineNumber`. You can already see on doing that why it makes sense to use meaningful variable names. You cannot simple run a search for `i` and replace all occurrences by `LineNumber`. You also cannot easily find out with a simple search where `i` is used as environment variable name and where `i` is used as loop variable. So you have made your coding work unnecessary difficult by not using meaningful and distinctive environment variable names.

Comment: I recommend further not using an arithmetic expression like `set /a i=0 ` or `set /a b=1` to define an environment variable with a value. That results just in execution of lots of completely unnecessary CPU instructions. Just use `set "i=0"` and `set "b=1"` (with better variable names). For an explanation read my answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

Comment: Last but not least the `for /L` loop could be coded also with `for /L %%# in (1,1,%i%) do echo System %%#: IP: !array[%%#]!`. There is no need to use an environment variable `b` if its value is always identical to value of loop variable `#` (or `i` in your code). And there is a line with `)` missing at end of the code. And replace `goto exit` by either `goto :EOF` or `exit /B`.

Comment: @Compo
I have run both test1.bat and test2.bat the way you described it.
Output from test1 is
192.168.4.10
192.168.4.12
192.168.4.75
192.168.4.103
192.168.4.104
192.168.4.105
and from test2
192.168.4.10
192.168.4.12
192.168.4.75
192.168.4.103
192.168.4.104
192.168.4.105

Comment: @Mofi Thank you very much for all the help and info!
Regarding the missing `)` I just forgot to include it in the code, my bad! The original for-Loop has a lot more going on after the line where I cut it but I didn't figure it'd be relevant since the program exits before that anyway.
Regarding the arithmetic expression, while setting a variable the way you did works, it seems like adding/substracting without using /a does either not work, or I might've gotten the syntax wrong.
I'm assuming you still need to use /a for every calculation you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having mysterious problems - turns out the code inside the for-Loop is very relevant indeed.
I had an "if" setup to check if one of my variables was empty

```
if %variable% == []
```

Batch doesn't like that for some reason. You have to do it like this:

```
if "%variable%" == []
```

Otherwise your script will render the whole for-Loop useless and just throw a generic `"(" was not expected at this point` as soon as it reaches it.
Thanks for the help and all info everyone though!

Comment: `if "%variable%" == []` will be never true and you know the reason after reading [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564). The best method to check if an environment variable with name `variable` is defined at all is using `if not defined variable command` or `if defined variable command`. The help output on running `if /?` in a command prompt window describes that method to check existence of an environment variable.

Comment: You wrote: "Batch doesn't like that for some reason." The batch file does not matter. The batch file is just a text file. The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` is first replacing `%variable%` by current value of the referenced environment variable with name `variable` during [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) the command line. So the __IF__ condition becomes `if  == []` on `variable` not defined at all. This __IF__ condition with no string left the comparison operator `==` is of invalid syntax and results in an error message on execution of __IF__ and a batch job exit.