# Read values from tokens in external file in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tokenize

I have the following file, which defined a version number of a project, which I am using in many places, like CMake files, python scripts, and other configurations. My only struggle is how can I read this in my batch file in windows? The syntax seems a little bit weird and I have to struggle with it for a few hours now and still can't figure it out.

Version.txt:

```
VERSION_MAJOR 09
VERSION_MINOR 02
VERSION_PATCH 21
VERSION_SUFFIX rc
```

What I am trying to do, is to use the values of the variables above in my bat script, something like this:

BatchScript.bat

```
VERSION_MAJOR = @VERSION_MARJO_FROM_FILE (e.g 09)
VERSION_MINOR = @VERSION_MARJO_FROM_FILE (e.g 02)
```

Comment: The `SET` command is used to assign values to a variable. The `FOR` command with the `/F` option is used to read a file.  Please show us a [mcve] of the code you are trying to use.

Comment: In `BatchScript.bat` use the command line `for /F "usebackq tokens=1*" %%I in ("Version.txt") do set "%%I=%%J"` and after that line there are defined the environment variables `VERSION_MAJOR` with string value `09` and `VERSION_MINOR` with string value `02` and `VERSION_PATCH` with string value `21` and `VERSION_SUFFIX` with string value `rc`. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` for help on this command. The string comparisons can be done with `if` using operator `==`. See also [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564).

Comment: It is of course also possible to use `for /F "usebackq tokens=1*" %%I in ("Version.txt") do set "%%I_FROM_FILE=%%J"` to define the four environment variables with names ending with `_FROM_FILE`. But better would be using `for /F "usebackq tokens=1*" %%I in ("Version.txt") do set "FILE_%%I=%%J"` to define the four environment variables with `FILE_` at beginning of their names. You know why this is better if you add to the batch file as next line `set FILE_` to output all environment variables with name beginning with `FILE_` and their current values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%i in (version.txt) do (
  if %%i==VERSION_MAJOR call set version_major%%=%%j
  if %%i==VERSION_MINOR call set version_minor%%=%%j
  if %%i==VERSION_PATCH call set version_patch%%
  if %%i==VERSION_SUFFIX call set version_suffix%%
)
```

Comment: As Mofi showed you in his code comments above you do not need to use an `IF` command to do what you need to do. Nor do you need the `CALL` command.