# How to start a GUI executable and a console program and terminate the console application on GUI application closed by the user?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am executing a script which starts an executable `proc1.exe`. When `proc1.exe` is running, the batch file has to start another executable `proc2.exe`.

Example: File `A.bat` runs `proc1.exe` with following requirements.

1. When `proc1.exe` is running, `proc2.exe` should run.
2. When `proc1.exe` is closed, `proc2.exe` should be terminated.

I tried this code:

```
tasklist /fi "ImageName eq proc1.exe" /fo csv 2>NUL|find /I "proc1.exe">NUL

if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" 
echo proc1.exe  is running
start /wait proc2.exe

else

taskkill /F /IM proc2.exe
```

When I run the script, the command window displays the error message:

> The syntax of tasklist command is incorrect.

What is the issue with the above `tasklist` command line?

I am not sure whether the `else` part would be achieved. How do I come back to `else` part in the script and kill `proc2.exe` after `proc1.exe` is terminated.

How could this be achieved?

---

Here are more information after post of first version of Mofi´s answer.

This is what I have tried and I think, I am near to the solution but need your support.

Batch file `A.bat` is modified to:

```
start bin\proc1.exe 2>&1
rem proc1.exe is running. Proc1.exe is a GUI application with buttons and
rem widgets. The cmd window and the GUI application window are opened now.

start /wait proc2.exe 2>&1
rem proc2.exe is running now too. It is a Windows console application.
rem A second console window is opened for that reason.
rem Both proc1.exe and proc2.exe are running as processes.
    
rem Now I want to check whether Proc1.exe is running or not.
rem If it is running do nothing, else terminate proc2.exe.
rem I have written a loop for that purpose. The issue is that
rem the control is not coming to the loop.

rem When I close the GUI application, the ELSE part should
rem be executed and proc2.exe should be terminated/killed.

rem How do I bring the control to loop label or how 
rem to signal proc1.exe is closed and run taskkill?

:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq proc1.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "proc1.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
    goto loop
) else (
    taskkill /F /IM proc2.exe  >NUL
)
```

Comment: check your `if` syntax (see `if /?`). As you wrote it, it can't work.

Comment: @Stephan. control is not coming to if part as of now. Issue at taskkill. I will check if issue

Comment: The `tasklist` line looks fine. Is there an error message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The task is very unclear.

1. Is `proc1.exe` started outside of the batch file or also by the batch file?
2. Is `proc1.exe` a Windows console or a Windows GUI application and does it open files for read/write operations or makes it registry reads/writes or does it open connections to other processes or even other devices?
3. Is `proc2.exe` a Windows console or a Windows GUI application and does it open files for read/write operations or makes it registry reads/writes or does it open connections to other processes or even other devices?
4. Is it possible to start `proc2.exe` a second before `proc1.exe` or does `proc2.exe` depend on an already running `proc1.exe` for a successful start?
5. Can be more instances of `proc1.exe` and/or `proc2.exe` already running before the batch file starts just `proc2.exe` or both applications?
6. Is it possible that even more instances of `proc1.exe` or `proc2.exe` are started by a user or any other process while the batch file observes the one or two processes started during execution of the batch file.
7. Is it really okay forcing a brutal **kill** of **all** running instances of `proc2.exe` by the operating system by using **TASKKILL** with the options `/F /IM proc2.exe` giving none of the running `proc2` processes the chance to gracefully terminate with closing connections, finishing all read/write operations, saving unsaved data and closing files?

Let me assume the answers on these seven questions are as follows:

1. The batch file always starts `proc1.exe`.
2. It is unknown what `proc1.exe` is and what it does.
3. It is unknown what `proc2.exe` is and what it does.
4. Yes, `proc2.exe` starts also successful on `proc1.exe` not already running.
5. Yes, that is indeed possible.
6. Yes, that is possible, too.
7. No, that is not okay. `proc2.exe` should close itself and should not be killed by the OS.

In this case can be used the following commented batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Define the two programs to run which can be even twice the same program.
set "ProgStart_FullName=%SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe"
set "ProgWait_FullName=%SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe"

rem Get just the file name of the first program with file extension.
for %%I in ("%ProgStart_FullName%") do set "ProgStart_FileName=%%~nxI"

rem Delete all environment variables of which name starts with
rem #PID_ in the local environment of this batch file context.
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set #PID_ 2^>nul') do "set %%I="

rem Get all process identifiers of all already running processes
rem of the executable which is started next by the the batch file.
for /F "tokens=2" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %ProgStart_FileName%" /NH') do set "#PID_%%I=1"

rem Start the program which should run as separate process.
start "" "%ProgStart_FullName%"

rem Find out the process identifier of just started program. There are
rem hopefully not started two instances of this program at the same time.
for /F "tokens=2" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq  %ProgStart_FileName%" /NH') do if not defined #PID_%%I set "#PID_OBSERVE=%%I" & goto StartNext
echo ERROR: Failed to start "%ProgStart_FullName%"!& echo(& pause & goto EndBatch

:StartNext
rem Start the next program and wait for its self-termination.
"%ProgWait_FullName%"

rem Check if the first started program is still running and send it in
rem this case the WM_CLOSE message for a graceful self-termination giving
rem the process the chance to close all connections, finish all file and
rem registry accesses with saving all unsaved data and close all files.
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "PID eq %#PID_OBSERVE%" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%ProgStart_FileName%" >nul || goto EndBatch
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /PID %#PID_OBSERVE% >nul 2>nul

rem Wait five seconds for the self-termination of the first started program.
rem A Windows GUI program should get even more time, especially if a user uses
rem that GUI program and the program asks the user if unsaved data should be
rem saved before exiting. How much time to wait depends on the application.
echo Wait for exit of "%ProgStart_FileName%" with PID %#PID_OBSERVE%" ...
set "LoopCount=5"
:WaitLoop
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "PID eq %#PID_OBSERVE%" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%ProgStart_FileName%" >nul || goto EndBatch
set /A LoopCount-=5
if not %LoopCount% == 0 goto WaitLoop

rem Force a brutal kill of the first started program by the operating system.
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /PID %#PID_OBSERVE% >nul 2>nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

This batch file demonstrates the process management by starting two instances of *Windows Notepad*. A user can start other *Notepad* instances before running the batch file and can also start even more *Notepad* processes while the two instances of *Notepad* started by the *Windows Command Processor* during processing of the batch file are still running and wait for user actions. The user can close the first batch started instance and later the second batch started instance of *Notepad*, but the opposite is also possible. If the user entered text into new file of first batch started instance without saving that text and closes first the second batch started instance, the first batch started instance of *Notepad* prompts the user if the unsaved text should be saved now. The user has five seconds time for the choice as otherwise the batch file runs **TASKKILL** with option `/F` to force a kill of the first batch started *Notepad* resulting in a loss of the input text.

The batch file as is cannot be used for executables with a space in file name.

The batch file cannot be used as posted here if `ProgStart_FullName` is `%CompSpec%` or `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`.

The environment variable `ProgStart_FullName` must be defined with the fully qualified file name of `proc2.exe` while the environment variable `ProgWait_FullName` must be defined with the fully qualified file name of `proc1.exe`. So, `proc2.exe` is started first as separate, parallel running process and next is started `proc1.exe` on which `cmd.exe` halts the batch file execution until `proc1.exe` exits itself. Then the batch file terminates also `proc2.exe` on still running or finally kills it if `proc2.exe` does not close itself within five seconds for whatever reason.

---

The task became more clear with the additional information added to the question.

The seven questions are answered as follows:

1. The batch file always starts `proc1.exe`.
2. The application `proc1.exe` is a Windows GUI application.
3. The application `proc2.exe` is a Windows console application.
4. `proc2.exe` must be started after `proc1.exe`.
5. There is neither `proc1.exe` nor `proc2.exe` started before batch file execution.
6. There are running never more than one `proc1.exe` one `proc2.exe`.
7. `proc2.exe` should close itself and should not be killed by the OS.

The commented batch file for this task with `proc1.exe` and `proc2.exe` in subdirectory `bin` of the batch file directory could be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FullNameProcess1=%~dp0bin\proc1.exe"
set "FullNameProcess2=%~dp0bin\proc2.exe"

rem Get just the file name of the two programs with file extension.
for %%I in ("%FullNameProcess1%") do set "FileNameProcess1=%%~nxI"
for %%I in ("%FullNameProcess2%") do set "FileNameProcess2=%%~nxI"

rem Start the GUI program which should run as separate process in foreground.
start "" "%FullNameProcess1%" 2>nul
rem Could the first program not be started at all?
if errorlevel 9059 echo ERROR: Failed to start "%FullNameProcess1%"!& echo(& pause & goto EndBatch

rem Start the console program which should run as separate process
rem without opening a console window.
start "" /B "%FullNameProcess2%"

rem Define an endless running loop searching once per second in the
rem task list if the first started GUI application is still running.
:WaitLoop
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %FileNameProcess1%" /NH | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "%FileNameProcess1%" >nul && goto WaitLoop

rem The first started GUI program is not running anymore. Check now if the
rem console program is still running and if that is the case, send it the
rem message to close itself.
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %FileNameProcess2%" /NH | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "%FileNameProcess2%" >nul || goto EndBatch
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM "%FileNameProcess2%" >nul 2>nul

rem Wait one second and check if the console program really terminated itself.
rem Otherwise force a brutal kill of the console program by the operating system.
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %FileNameProcess2%" /NH | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "%FileNameProcess2%" >nul && %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /IM "%FileNameProcess2%" >nul 2>nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The batch file as is cannot be used for executables with a space in file name.

The batch file cannot be used if `proc2.exe` is in real `cmd.exe` because of `taskkill.exe /IM "cmd.exe"` results in termination of **all** running `cmd` processes including the one processing the batch file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `taskkill /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `timeout /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul` and `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on the **FOR** command lines to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes these command lines before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` with `^` appended as additional arguments.

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of unconditional command operator `&` and conditional command operator `||` and correct syntax for an **IF** condition with an **ELSE** branch. The usage of `"%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0"` is neither described by the usage help of command **IF** nor is it ever a good idea to use this [string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) for exit code evaluation in a batch file.

Answer (score -1):

```
This is I want I tried and I am near to the solution but need your support.

A.bat file
start bin\proc1.exe 2>&1
::proc1.exe gets running. Proc1.exe is a gui application with buttons and widgets. cmd window and gui application gets opened.
start /wait proc2.exe 2>&1
    ::proc2.exe gets running it is a windows console, a cmd windows gets 
    opened. Both proc1.exe and proc2.exe are running as process
    
    Now I want to check whether Proc1.exe is running or not if it is running do nothing, else kill proc2.exe
    for that I have written a loop, the issue is control
 is not coming to loop.
    
    when I close the gui application, else part to be executed and proc2. exe should be terminated/killed.
 How do I bring the control to loop lable or how 
    to signal , proc1.exe is closed , u run loop.

:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq proc1.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "proc1.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
    goto loop
) else (
    taskkill /F /IM proc2.exe  >NUL
)
```

Comment: You should not post additional information in an __answer__. That information and batch file code does not answer your question. You should edit your __question__ by clicking on gray displayed __Edit__ link below the blue displayed tags of your question and add there the additional information. Then click on gray displayed __Delete__ link here at bottom of your __answer__ to delete it (in real just hide it for most Stack Overflow users). I will look on your additional information and will update my answer accordingly. But it can take 24 hours before my answer is updated, please be patient.

Comment: `start /wait` will wait for the program to end before continuing the code. The solution might be as simple as removing `/wait`.

Comment: @Stephan. Thank you for the solution. The control is now coming to loop but            tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq proc1.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "proc1.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" . though proc1.exe is running the env variable errorlevel always returns 1.  what is the reason why it is not returning 0 though proc1.exe is running.

Comment: unknown - works for me. Temporarily remove `2>nul` and `>nul` to check what's going on.

Comment: @Stephan. After removing 2>nul and > nul, it doesn't work for me. and tasklist command and env variable always returns 1. what is the reason and how to fix it.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't helpful. What exactly is it (not) doing? What's the exact output you get?

Comment: @Stephan, it is going to else part and killing proc2.exe,  not coming to if part though the proc1.exe is running

Comment: [*sigh*] What's the output of `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq proc1.exe" | find /I /N "proc1.exe"`?