# tracert.exe not redirecting from inside schtasks

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, traceroute

So if  'tracert google.com >>tracelog.txt'  works from a command line, what do I have to do to get it to redirect to a file from inside a batch script, considering it's being called by schtasks.exe?

I read on the schtasks 'help' screen something about two sets of quotes, one for cmd and one for schtasks, but I don't understand how that applies here.

The object is to run tracert on a problematic url to discover any overt latency in any of the hops. The task is meant to run once, repeating every x minutes for a duration of t time while appending the results to a log file (debugging an online game).

So that's the part that's got me, getting a log file out of it.

As always, any help is appreciated.

```
@echo off

if [%1]==[] goto usage

set "START=13:10"
set "DUR=00:06"
set  TRACE="tracert.exe %1 >>C:\urltrace\tracelog.txt"

SCHTASKS /CREATE /TN "URLtrace Task" /TR %TRACE% /RL HIGHEST /SC ONCE /RI 2 /DU %DUR% /ST %START% /F    
exit /B 1

:usage
@echo Syntax: urltrace <url> Examp: urltrace google.com
exit /B 1
```

Comment: This ```if [%1]==[] ...``` has no place in any batch file for Windows. It should be changed to: ```If "%~1" == "" ...```

Comment: @compo, yes. From my limited reading, it seems there are two schools of though on that. I've seen answers here on SOF that would pose just the opposite opinion. In any case, very gracious of all of you to weight in.

Comment: Any school of thought contrary to what I posted, @morongo, is incorrect. _BTW, I specifically stated Windows, not DOS_.

Comment: @Compo Agreed, Mofi's explanation clarified the reasoning for using "" as opposed to []. I rarely use batch files and certainly not to the extent that you and Mofi do, thanks again for the guidance and your interest in correcting my shortcomings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task can be done with a batch file with just two command lines:

```
@if "%~1" == "" echo Syntax: %~n0 ^<domain name ^| IP address^>& echo Example: %~n0 google.com& exit /B
@%SystemRoot%\System32\tracert.exe %1 >>"%~dp0TraceLog.txt"
```

**START** is an internal command of `cmd.exe` processing a batch file. It is possible using the string `START` as label or as name of an environment variable but it is advisable not doing that. There should be used a different variable name like `StartTime`. A label is not really needed here.

The not necessary definition of the environment variable **TRACE** can be wrong depending on value of `%1` (first argument string passed to the batch file) because of `%1` could contain `"` at the beginning and the end of the argument string which requires escaping them in the command line executing `%SystemRoot%\System32\schtaks.exe`.

The trace route tool should never be run with a complete url. It should be run always with an **IP address** or a **domain name** of which `%SystemRoot%\System32\tracert.exe` first accesses the primary and if not available the secondary DNS (domain name system server) to get the IP address of that domain name. An IP address as well as a domain name cannot contain a space character or other characters with a special meaning for `cmd.exe` and it is possible to pass that argument string always without surrounding `"` to `tracert.exe` which means no quotes escaping would be necessary in `schtasks.exe` argument string. There is nevertheless used in the second command line `%1` instead of `%~1` as the user calling the batch file could pass an argument string to the batch file containing even an ampersand character in which case the argument string was enclosed in `"` by the user. The string passed to the batch file is passed further as is to the trace route tool for that reason.

There is no reason for creating a scheduled task just to run the trace route executable. The access of external networks does usually not depend on a user account or a specific access time.

The square brackets have no special meaning for the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` processing a batch file. The condition `if [%1]==[]` is of syntax from `COMMAND.COM` of MS-DOS, Windows 95, Windows 98 and Windows ME. There should be used `"` on comparing two strings instead of `[` and `]` because of the double quotes have a special meaning for `cmd.exe` in comparison to `COMMAND.COM`. The character `"` restricts the beginning and the end of an argument string on which all characters between should be interpreted literally by `cmd.exe` with exception of `%` (environment variable, loop variable or batch argument reference) and `!` on delayed variable expansion is enabled too. Please read [symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564). This answer explains in full details how a string comparison is done by command **IF** of `cmd.exe` and why `if "%~1" == ""` is best to check if a batch file was started without any argument string or with an empty argument string by using `""`.

The first command line uses this quite safe string comparison and outputs two lines for the user if the batch file is executed without passing an IP address or a domain name to the batch file.

The output lines reference with `%~n0` the file name of the batch file without file extension to output the usage information always with correct name.

The characters `<` and `>` and `|` are interpreted as redirection operators on found by `cmd.exe` in a command line outside a double quoted argument string and not escaped with character `^` for being interpreted as literal characters which is the reason for escaping them all with `^` in the first output usage information line.

A space character between the end of a text output with command **ECHO** and the unconditional command operator `&` would be output also by **ECHO** as trailing space because of **ECHO** does not interpret a space as argument string separator. This is the reason for no space left to the two `&` although the trailing space cannot be seen by a user of the batch file.

`%~dp0` references the drive and path of argument 0 which is the full path of the batch file. This path always ends with a backslash. The file `TraceLog.txt` is created respectively extended in the batch file directory and not in the current directory with the standard output of the trace route tool. It could be a good idea to append on the second command line also  `2>&1` to get an error output of the trace route tool also written into the file `TraceLog.txt`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `if /?`
- `tracert /?`

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))

Comment: You have indeed exceeded my expectations with this most thorough explanation! All I was after was how to get a file-dump from schtasks... As I explained to Compos, I rarely use batch files and when I do, it's normally for dead simple tasks. I do the majority of my scripting/programming in C/C++, javascript, python, lisp, php and node, along with any attendant html and css, in those cases that require it. This use-case required scheduling tracert to run the way I described for a reason, it succeeded in uncovering a problem area. Thanks again for everything.

Answer (score 1):

```batch-file
@echo off
if "%1" equ "" exit /b
setlocal
set start_time=13:10
if "%2" neq "" set start_time=%2
set folder="C:\Program Files\urltrace"
if not exist %folder% mkdir %folder%
if not exist %folder% exit /b
set file=%folder%\urltrace.bat
if not exist %file% (
    @echo off >> %file%
    echo cd /d %folder% >> %file%
    echo set url="" >> %file%
    echo call task.bat >> %file%
    echo tracert.exe %%url%% ^>^>tracelog.txt^&exit /b  >> %file%
)
echo @set url=%1 > %folder%\task.bat
SCHTASKS /ru  "SYSTEM" /CREATE /TN "URLtrace Task" /tr "'cmd.exe' /c @call 'C:\Program Files\urltrace\urltrace.bat'" /sc ONCE /RI 2 /DU 00:06  /ST %start_time% /f
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this solution. I actually preferred Mofi's take on this, but since he/she only posted a comment, you earn the point. Thanks again.