# If statement in Windows Batch file always evaluating first statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have a batch single bat file to start and stop an installed application.  In this case, it is SolidWorks but it could be any application (Excel, Word, etc.).

The bat files takes 2 parameters.  The first parameter is "START" or "STOP".  The 2nd parameter is the directory where the application resides.

The issue I'm having is the bat file always run the first statement.  I'm assuming because the first parameter is always evaluating incorrectly.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@echo off

echo %1

IF /i %1% == "START" goto startsw

IF /i %1% == "STOP" goto stopsw

:startsw
echo "starting..."
start "" /d %2 SLDWORKS.exe
goto commonexit

:stopsw
echo "stopping..."
taskkill /F /IM SLDWORKS.exe
goto commonexit

:commonexit
pause
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your arguments include the quotes? `"START"` is never equal to `START`. If the arguments have no quotes, neither of your `if`s "fire" and the code just continues with the next line, which happens to be the `:startsw` subroutine (just not as subroutine, but a main code). Add a `goto :eof` (or jump somewhere else in your code) to avoid that "fall-through"

Comment: Example oneliner: ```If /I "%~1" == "START" (GoTo startsw) Else (If /I "%~1" == "STOP" (goto stopsw) Else GoTo commonexit)```.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan.  
The arguments I'm passing in are
C:\Temp>SolidWorksStartStop.bat START "C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Answered by @Stephen, my comparison was incorrectly using quotes. The corrected code is:

```
@echo off

echo %1

IF %1% == START goto startsw

IF %1% == STOP goto stopsw

:startsw
echo "starting..."
start "" /d %2 SLDWORKS.exe
goto commonexit

:stopsw
echo "stopping..."
taskkill /F /IM SLDWORKS.exe
goto commonexit

:commonexit
pause
```

Comment: `if %1%` is incorrect - it should be `if %1`, or `if /i %1` for case-insensitive, or preferably `if /i "%~1"=="keyword"`, which is more robust.

Comment: This code is still incorrect. Please open a command prompt window, run `call /?` and read the output usage help explaining how to reference batch file arguments. The first argument is referenced with `%1` without an additional `%` after the argument number. `%~1` references the first argument string with surrounding `"` removed on first argument is passed to the batch file with surrounding `"`. Read also [symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) explaining in full details how __IF__ compares two strings.

Comment: The first __IF__ should be `IF /I "%~1" == "START" GOTO startsw`. That makes it possible running the batch file with `"START"` or `"start"` or `Start` or `staRT` as first argument. The second __IF__ should be `IF /I "%~1" == "STOP" GOTO stopsw` making it possible running the batch file with `"STOP"` or `"stop"` or `Stop` or `sToP` as first argument. The next command line after second __IF__ should be either `GOTO commonexit` or `EXIT /B` for exiting the batch file processing on batch file is executed without any argument string or with the empty argument string `""` or something different.