# Batch Crashes Without Error, How Can I Find The Problem?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

Everything was working when I used a test link such as `youtube` or `youtube.com` or even `https://youtube.com/test` and it would continue to the next line. However, when I input an actual YouTube URL, CMD crashes giving no error. I even turned `ECHO on` to try and see what was going on, but it would just crash.

```bash
@ECHO OFF
 
:back1
echo Please enter a file name, make sure to add ".webm" to the end for formatting reasons:
set/p "file=>"
if x%file:.webm=%==x%file% goto linkER
goto back2
 
:linkER
cecho {0C}INVALID ENTRY it is CRITICAL to get this part right! {#}
goto back1
 
:back2
echo Please paste the YouTube link:
set/p "link=>"
if %link%==0 (goto Invalid)
if x%link:youtube=%==x%link% goto Youtube
goto start_time
 
:Invalid
cecho {0C}INVALID ENTRY {#}
goto back2
 
:Youtube
cecho {0C}INVALID ENTRY: Must contain "Youtube" {#}
goto back2
```

This should be the only block of code needed to get the point, though there is much more.

Does anyone have any ideas what it could be or what I could try?

Comment: A batch file is a text file containing command lines to process by the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe`. A batch file cannot __crash__ for that reason. `cmd.exe` could crash as being a program with CPU instructions. Please read [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) explaining how to run a batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on it in *Windows File Explorer* without `@ECHO OFF` at top to see which command line results in a syntax error on execution with the error message output by `cmd` before it exits batch processing.

Comment: The first syntax error is in the line `set/p "file=>"` where a space is missing between the command `set` (argument 0) and its option `/p` (argument 1). Other syntax errors are `cecho`. This is not a known [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands). It should be most likely `echo`. I recommend reading also my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Comment: There should be inserted below `:back1` and the `echo` command line `set "file="`. The next line should be modified from `set/p "file=>"` to `set /P "file=>" || goto linkER`. The next two lines should be `set "file=%file:"=%"` to remove all `"` from user input string and `if not defined file goto linkER` in case of the user entered just one or more `"`. The command line `if x%file:.webm=%==x%file% goto linkER` should be replaced by `for %%G in ("%file%") do if /I not "%%~xG" == ".webm" if  "%%~xG" == "" (set "file=%file%.webm") else goto linkER`

Comment: The first __IF__ condition of __FOR__ command line is false on user input string ends case-insensitive with `.webm` in which case nothing else is done on this command line. But if the user input string does __not__ end case-insensitive with `.webm` the second __IF__ is executed which checks if the user input file name is without a file extension. If that is the case there is appended `.webm` to the file name and the batch processing continues on next command line. Otherwise the input file name has a different file extension and the batch processing is continued for that reason below `linkEr`.

Comment: The second user prompt for the URL should be coded similar to make the batch file fail-safe against by mistake or by intention incorrect user input and secure. `cecho` should obviously output the messages with color. If `cecho` is a batch file in directory or your batch file, replace `cecho` by `call "%~dp0cecho.bat"` or `call "%~dp0cecho.cmd"` depending on file extension of the batch file. If `cecho` is an executable in directory of your batch file, replace `cecho` by `"%~dp0cecho.exe"` to get your batch file working independent on which directory is the current directory.

Comment: See also my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564). It explains in full details how the internal command __IF__ of `cmd.exe` makes a string comparison. `if x%link:youtube=%==x%link% goto Youtube` is not fail-safe. There should be used `set "link="` and `set /P "link=>" || goto Invalid` and `set "link=%link:"=%"` and `if not defined link goto Invalid` and `if "%link:youtube=%" == "%link%" goto Youtube`.

Comment: Hi Mofi! I want to thank you for all your help thus far. Despite the first part working, I have significantly reduced its size and compiled it way better thanks to your help. For the cecho, I have it installed and  thus cecho will work. Since this file is only for me and close friends it doesn't need too many failsafes and I can ensure cecho is installed on their machines too. A few quick questions I have, what does the '||' do in the set command, and what are all the / commands? I have seen many like /p, /i, /l etc but I am unsure what they all do and research has proved unfruitful.

Comment: Once again, please read [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) where I have explained what `|| command` after `set /P "variable=prompt"` is for. The command after `||` is executed if the user inputs nothing, i.e. presses just __RETURN__ or __ENTER__ (perhaps per mistake). See also: [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `set /?` and read the output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page. Then you know what the option `/P` of command __SET__ is for (Prompting a user for a string). Run `if /?` and read the output help and you should know that the option `/I` is for a case-Insensitive string comparison. Run `for /?` and read the output help for getting knowledge how command __FOR__ works depending on the used options. Run `help` for an incomplete list of commands

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue could be the way of handling real YouTube URLS. Try altering the line where it checks the presence of the link/URL. This will ensure that it proceeds to the `start-time`.

You might want to change this line:

`if x%link:youtube=%==x%link% goto Youtube`

To something like:

`if not "%link:youtube=%"=="" goto start_time`

let me know if this makes a difference.

Comment: Hi JoyNa! Thank you for your input here, but what I am attempting to do in this equasion is remove the prase "youtube" from the string "link" then compare it to the original link string to see if the original link string has "youtube" in it anywhere. The reason for this is to check if it is a YouTube URL